# Issue with file download in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC application for file download and complete file info I have saved in view using hidden field like FileName, ContentType, FilePath.

I have used one anchor tag for download link.

Below is the javascript code for calling FileResult action method:

```
window.location = '/mycontroller/DownloadFile';
```

Below is my controller action of file result:

```html
 public FileResult DownloadFile()
 {                
     var fileName = "Capture.PNG";
     var filePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("/Content/ArticleImages/368bc1e6-228b-42f3-bb55-4b8463f69faa.PNG"));
     var fileCType = "image/png";
     byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
     return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
 }
```

As you can see in above method i have hardcoded filename and filepath where file is exist in this path.

I have tried to send this data through ajax call but this method accept only get method not post so I am not able to send this data through ajax call.

For testing purpose i hardcoded value here and tried to download.
Now another issue is when click on download link after hitting this method process is asking for save file location after saving file location in browser file is downloading but in stuck mode and file is not downloading completely.

Need help.

Comment: You can pass FileName, ContentType, FilePath as query string and you need to fetch them in your DownloadFile() method. For example. window.location = '/mycontroller/DownloadFile?FileName=myFilename&ContentType=myContectType&FilePath=myFilePath'

Comment: @PrityKumari Did you try: `return File(fileBytes, fileCType, fileName);` ?. I see, though you declared content type but not using it to return, which can cause the issue.

Comment: @PrityKumari " this method accept only get method not post so I am not able to send this data through ajax call" which I guess you are confused little over Ajax functionality. Ajax can make `GET` request also, if that is what the exact problem you want to convey.

Comment: "I have to tried to send this through ajax call" - why?  Just set `window.location = '/mycontroller/DownloadFile';` and let the browser handle saving/viewing the file.  What are you going to do with the file's bytes if you receive them in an ajax request?

Comment: Hi Siva, Thanks for your response. If you see the code i am returning filebytes, mime type and filename and sure i will try to use querystring for sending data from view to FileResult action method.

Comment: Hi Siva, as you suggested i added one more route table in route.config for download file parameter and in window.location url with action i pass these parameters as querystring. One more thing when i was getting bytes of the file i did not use server.map path and url.content code. These changes i have done also and it is working fine now no issues. Please reply your comment as answer so i will accept your answer and upvote your answer.